# Incrementing this.clicks from a function inside a prototype function

Tags: javascript, prototype, this

This code displays two cats and the number of times each cat is clicked, how can I increment the .clicks property of each cat from inside the Cat.prototype.clickInc() method?

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
    var cats = [];

  var Cat = function(id, image_path) {

    this.id = id;
    this.image_path = image_path;
    this.clicks = 0;

};


 Cat.prototype.clickInc = function() {

  $('#'+this.id).click(function(){

     this.clicks++;

      return this.clicks;
   });
  };//use a closure here

var poly = new Cat("poly", "poly.jpg");
var chewie = new Cat("chewie", "chewie.jpg");
cats.push(poly);
cats.push(chewie);

for(i=0; i<cats.length; i++)
{    
    var catInfo = '<div class="cats"><div id="'+cats[i].id+'"><img src='+cats[i].image_path+'><h3>'+cats[i].id+'</h3></div><div class="clickNos"><span ="label">Number of clicks</span><span class="clicks">'+cats[i].clicks+'</span></div></div>';
    $("#container").append(catInfo);
    cats[i].clickInc();
}


});
```

Comment: The irregular indentation in the code here makes this question ***very*** difficult to read. Just a tip: you will get help faster if you present your problem in an easy-to-read format with properly indented code (and anyone who works on your code in the future will thank you, too!)

Comment: @FelixKling `javascript` at Question has more issues that only accessing correct `this` within event handler, including attempt to `return` from within `click` handler instead of setting `.innerHTML` of appropriate element, which is not addressed at linked Question/Answers

Comment: @guest271314 I agree and reopened. Like Felix, I didn't understand the OP wanted the `<span class="clicks">` element to be updated, but now that you point it out, that seems like the correct interpretation of the question.

Answer (score 1):

`this` is not `Cat` within `.click()` handler. Also, you cannot `return` from an event handler. Use `.next(".clickNos")` with `.find(".clicks")` to select next `.clicks` element relative to clicked `<img>` element; set `.html()` of matched element to `.clicks` property of `Cat` instance.

```
  Cat.prototype.clickInc = function() {
    var _cat = this;
    $('#' + this.id).click(function() {
      _cat.clicks++;
      $(this).next(".clickNos").find(".clicks").html(" " +_cat.clicks);
    });
  };
```

jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/9cykvbyv/1/